# Laravel7 query wrap with "not"

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

How to create "NOT" wrapped criteria, ie:

```
WHERE
  id=1 AND NOT (tag='foo' OR tag='bar')
```

I know I can wrap with closure

```
$q->where('id', 1)
  ->where(function ($iq) {
    $iq->where('tag', 'foo')
      ->orWhere('tag', 'bar');
  });
```

Something like this (which **does not work**):

```
$q->where('id', 1)
  ->where('!=', function ($iq) {
    $iq->where('tag', 'foo')
      ->orWhere('tag', 'bar');
  });
```

Edit:
I have Laravel7

Comment: Ookay. Forgot to specify, I have Laravel7 and this seems not to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10 has [where not clause](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-not-clauses) but Laravel 7 does not.

But this works:

```php
$q->where('id', 1)
  ->where(function ($iq) {
    $iq->where('tag', 'foo')
      ->orWhere('tag', 'bar');
  }, null, null, 'and not');
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific example you have provided is better done as:

```php
$q->where('id', 1)
  ->whereNotIn('tag', ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Comment: True but it was more complex than that.